# I can't assign an exact exported value in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to implement a logging library inside my project, but I'm getting a weird error during compile time, even though I'm passing the exact expected value (not even only the type) as defined in the custom type. Here's my code:

Custom types in library:

```
enum SupportedAdapters {
  Console = 'console',
  Sentry = 'sentry',
}

type ConsoleAdapterSettings = {
  name: SupportedAdapters.Console,
  config: LoggerAdapterConfig,
}

type SentryAdapterSettings = {
  name: SupportedAdapters.Sentry,
  config: SentryAdapterConfig,
}

type AdapterSettings = ConsoleAdapterSettings | SentryAdapterSettings

interface ConstructorParams {
  adapters: Array<AdapterSettings>,
}

...

export {
  SupportedAdapters as Adapters,
};
```

then, I'm instantiating this class in my project like this:

```
const sentryAdapter = {
    name: Adapters.Sentry,
    config: {
      ...
    },
  };

  const loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory({
    adapters: [sentryAdapter],
  });
```

as you can see, for the name, I'm using the exact value of `SupportedAdapters.Sentry` (which is exported as Adapters, so that's why I'm using it as `Adapters.Sentry` in my code. However, I'm getting this error:

> root.ts:48:16 - error TS2322: Type '{ name: Adapters; config: {
> logLevel: LogLevels; skipTimestamps: boolean; dsn: string;
> environment: string | undefined; }; }' is not assignable to type
> 'AdapterSettings'.   Type '{ name: Adapters; config: { logLevel:
> LogLevels; skipTimestamps: boolean; dsn: string; environment: string |
> undefined; }; }' is not assignable to type 'SentryAdapterSettings'.
> Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
> Type 'SupportedAdapters' is not assignable to type 'SupportedAdapters.Sentry'.
>
> 48     adapters: [sentryAdapter],

I tried hardcoding "sentry" as value in my code, but as expected, it doesn't work - only the error changed to `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SupportedAdapters.Sentry'`. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

Minimum reproducible example:

1. Create a new project
2. `npm i @luckbox/logger-factory`
3. Create a file with the following code and try to compile it:

> import { LoggerFactory, Adapters, LogLevels } from
> '@luckbox/logger-factory';
>
> const sentryAdapter = {   name: Adapters.Sentry,   config: {
> logLevel: LogLevels.Warn,
> dsn: 'https://somerandomstring@sentry.rtgdev.com/5',   }, };
>
> const loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory({   adapters: [sentryAdapter],
> });

Please tell me if something else is needed.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve], possibly as a link to an appropriately configured web IDE?  I can't easily reproduce your issue in my own environment, so it would be helpful if you could actually demonstrate the issue to us.  Otherwise this is more like remote technical support which is not something I excel at.

Comment: Couldn't really get it to run in a web IDE (tried jsfiddle and TS' own playground) but I'll updated the opening post with a minimum reproducible example that you can reproduce locally.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not going to install things on my computer to answer SO questions; maybe someone else without that restriction will come along and help.  Otherwise you could try creating a web IDE project at at https://codesandbox.io/ or https://stackblitz.com/ ?